# Not able to send message using smack Android

Tags: android, smack

i am trying to send message to client but always getting this exception: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.
 Following are my code to send message:

```
  ChatManager chatMngr = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

Chat chat   =   chatMngr.createChat(toName + "@stag-api.artistaloud.com", FrgChatRoom.this);

```
                 try {

                 chat.sendMessage(txtChatMsg.getText().toString().trim());

                 } catch (Exception e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();

                 }
```

When i am relogin before send the message. its working fine...please reply..

Answer (score 0):

this `exception` occurs while you are not connected with `Xmpp server`.
  first insure that are you connect with server or not?.and for get   connected with server with `asmack libs` use this code:

```
private class ConnectToXmpp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration( server_host, SERVER_PORT);
      XMPPConnection m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
try {
     SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
     config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);     
     m_connection.connect();
    Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

   }

}
```

and now you can execute this as `new ConnectToXmpp().execute();`
and for sending message you have to create `chat` like:

```
    ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("jsmith@jivesoftware.com", new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
});

try {
    newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
}
catch (XMPPException e) {
    System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
}
```

and Chat.sendMessage(String) method is a convenience method that creates a Message object, sets the body using the String parameter, then sends the message. 
and then use this code sniipet for send message:

```
Message newMessage = new Message();
newMessage.setBody("Howdy!");
message.setProperty("favoriteColor", "red");
newChat.sendMessage(newMessage);
```

and for more information [see](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/messaging.html) this link.

Comment: But i am alreday connected with server. yet i am not able to send message

Comment: dear it may be possible that your session is not maintained.because,as exception shows client is not no longer connected with  server.